# Multiple build with MavenCli.doMain (maven-embedder) failures

Tags: java, maven, maven-embedder

I have program which in a loop:

1. Do checkout
2. Build project with MavenCli
3. Analyze with Findbugs

But, MavenCli.doMain works only once and return 1 second time.

Pom file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
            <artifactId>aether-connector-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-http-lightweight</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Code:

```
   public class AnalysisRunner {

    private static final MavenCli MAVEN_CLIENT = new MavenCli();
    private static final String[] MAVEN_BUILD_COMMAND = {"clean", "install"};

    public void runMavenBuild() {
        System.out.println(MAVEN_CLIENT.doMain(MAVEN_BUILD_COMMAND, LOCAL_REPOSITORY.getAbsolutePath(), System.out, System.out));
    }
}
```

First iteration maven's output:

```
0
```

Second iteration maven's output:

```
1
```

Also, I found this in Maven-embedder sources:

```
catch( ExitException e )
         {
             return e.exitCode;
         }
         catch ( UnrecognizedOptionException e )
         {
             // pure user error, suppress stack trace
             return 1;
         }
         catch ( Exception e )
         {
             CLIReportingUtils.showError( logger, "Error executing Maven.", e, cliRequest.showErrors );
             return 1;
         }
```

I think that I forgot to close smth but what and where?

**THE BEST SOLUTION I FOUND:**

Is to use [Maven Invoker](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/index.html) instead of maven-embedder.